# jQuery smooth scroll to anchor if you're outside front page in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have o wordpress site with a wordpress standard menu. In the frontpage of my site, I have different sections and I use jquery smooth scroll to slide from one section to another. Here is the example of the menu link:

```
<a class="anchor_scroll" href="#services">Services</a></li>
```

Here is the jquery I use for smooth scroll:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".anchor_scroll").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //calculate destination place
    var dest=0;
    if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
        dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
    }else{
        dest=$(this.hash).offset().top-150;
    }
    //go to destination
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1500,'swing');
});
$('.main-navigation li').click(
    function(e)
    {
        $('.main-navigation li').removeClass('active');
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
    }
);
});
```

Well it works fine if I'm in the front page of my website, where all the sections exist. However, If I'm under different page, i.e. http://localhost/?p=665, the scroll doesnt work. Maybe someone could provide me a modified js code which would solve this issue?

Comment: So when you're on your home page and click on menu links, they scroll down to sections? That works because links point on the section ID. If you're on another page, and the links in the menu don't point to id's on this page, and if your menu anchors don't have the class `.anchor_scroll` then scrolling won't happen.

Comment: Thank you @dingo_d. I actually understand the problem and why it doesn't work. I'm just not very good in jquery, to modify the code according my needs.

Comment: I don't think you need to adjust the jquery. On your second page, do you have sections with the same id's as on the front page? And when you inspect the menu anchors, do they have the `.anchor_scroll` class?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @dingo_d. No, on the second page I don't have sections with the same id's. The sections are only on the frontpage. If user is not on a front page. but clicks the link to the section, I want him to be redirected to the frontpage and smoothly slided to the desired destination.

Comment: Has anybody any solution to this issue?